# Resource leak: stream is never closed

Tags: android, warnings

Short way to reproduce the problem in my real project. Environment: Android SDK 1.16, Eclipse 4.2.0, Windows. Create default Android application and add the following code to MainActivity.java:

```
private void Save1(boolean externalStorage)
{
    String s = "12345";
    File file;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    if ( externalStorage )
    {
        try
        {
            file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "log");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);                  // Resource leak: 'fos' is never closed
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            fos = openFileOutput("log", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    try
    {
        fos.write(s.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        return;
    }
}

private void Save2(boolean externalStorage)
{
    String s = "12345";
    File file;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try
    {
        file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "log");
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);                  // OK
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        fos.write(s.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Line `fos = new FileOutputStream(file)` in `Save1` function, warning: `Resource leak: 'fos' is never closed`

The same line in `Save2` function: no warnings.

Please don't send untested answers, the problem is not so simple as it looks. Adding `fos.close()` to different parts of the function doesn't help.

Comment: Wow.  Compiler bug?  I can see no possible path when fos is not closed.  Watching with interest....

Comment: @Simon: if this is compiler bug, I don't care - I can write two different functions. I just want to know whether this is my mistake or not.

Comment: Actually, more like a Lint bug but I'm checking it out.

Comment: Now if I replace the return with e.printStackTrace(); in the catch block of the if block, the warning go away..

Comment: @Simon: Android SDK 1.16, Eclipse 4.2.0, Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: @Praful Bhatnagar - yes, just commenting off this return removes the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It also go away if i add an finally block to the try in the if block like this:

```
if (externalStorage) {
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),
                        "log"));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                return;
            } finally {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else {
            try {
                fos = openFileOutput("log", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                return;
            }
        }
```

It is getting interesting...

So my guess would be, So if you are opening an Stream in a try block and catch block has an return statement then there should be a finally block that close the stream.

Something like that..

A tried the same code in a simple java project in eclipse and still got the warning. So it looks like is not related to lint or android. It looks like the eclipse compiler issue. Following is the code, I had to create a dummy openFileOutput() method since it is not available n java:

```
private void Save1(boolean externalStorage) {
    String s = "12345";
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    if (externalStorage) {
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("c://", "log"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return;
        }
    } else {
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput("log", -1);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return;
        }
    }

    try {
        fos.write(s.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return;
    }
}

/**
 * @param string
 * @param i
 * @return
 */
private FileOutputStream openFileOutput(String string, int i)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
        return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this removes the warning. I still think that this is Lint bug, and not my fault, because the second function compiles without warnings. Thanks.

Comment: add  `if (fos != null) { fos.close(); }` to avoid `NullPointerException`

Comment: Just check with a simple java project and still got the same warning. So it looks like it is not lint or android compiler issue.... 

I added java code in the answer...

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer, but added here for clarity to the OP and other readers rather than a comment.

I've tested this in IDEA 11.2 API 15 using the current versions of the platform tool chain (Rev 14 Oct 2012) and there is no lint warning, compile error or runtime error.  I forced the method to go through each path by creating exceptions and setting useExternalStorage both true and false.

My guess is this is a lint/compile error in your tool chain or possibly Eclipse (although unlikely, does Eclipse itself do any checking like this?).

[EDIT]

Just a thought, (and I would test but I've forgotten how to use Eclipse) but FileInputStream(file) might throw a SecurityException which would be thrown to somewhere up in your call stack.  What happens if you catch it?

[EDIT]

This is the closest warning I get, and not at all relevant.  I'm convinced the warning is not down to you.

[image: Screen shot for IDEA 11.2, API 15, SDK tools rev 14]

Comment: It looks like finally this will be the answer.

Comment: Even replacing FileNotFoundException with Exception doesn't remove the warning.

Comment: Though this looks like Lint bug, I accept the answer which allows me to get rid of this warning. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case of an `Exception`, `fos` wont be closed. Adding a `finally` to the `try-catch` would solve this issue.

```
    try
    {
        fos = openFileOutput("log", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        return;
    }
    //add this:
    finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            fos.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. Your answer is not compiled. 2. You are trying to change the place that doesn't have any warning.

Comment: if you open something in try, close it in finally - simple rule. that was just an example 'place'. you should do that in every single try catch... don't have to compile that to know this - see accepted answer

Comment: again - this is not supposed to be ready made solution. this is a hint on where your mistakes are: make sure that in every possibility the resource will be closed (if not null). looking at your question your not doing this. one way to do this is to use finally. btw neither lint nor the compiler will complain if you follow this advice (tested). and no this is not a compiler bug...